# View attachments in popup when using the editor widget

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, fields-attributes, popup

I am using ArcGIS javascript API to construct an editor app for a layer. I am using the default out of the box editor widget to edit and display data for an app. The layers I am editing contain attachments, which show up as a link within the editor's attribute viewer. Attachments are by default opened in a new window. I would like a dialog box with the attachment ( which is images) to load via a ajax request once the link is clicked.

Has anybody been able to get attachments, such an image to open in a popup of some type, while using the default editor widget?

My logic was to trigger an event handler that changes the link to the attachment, after the attribute inspector loads but I can't seem to find an event that is triggered during that time.

Am I going at this from the right approach, or would there be a better way to accomplish this with the default editor? I know you could probably write a custom widget to to do this, but I would prefer to stick with the functionality that the editor widget provides.